# c# windows service does change the configuration require reinstall and install again?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, windows-services

I developed a windows service and installed it on a server using

installUtil command

now the client wants to change the username, the username is already configured in the configuration file for the windows service, my question is that is it enough if it just changed that field in the configuration file? or i need to uninstall the service and re install it again?

Comment: That depends on how the service is implemented. What is the username used for? Is the username read from the config file every time the service needs it? Or is it stored somewhere when the service started/was installed. If it is the username the service is running under, you can change that on the properties on the service in services.msc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to reinstall the service.

1. Stop the service
2. Overwrite the necessary files in the service path
3. Start the service again